# How to read audio file in defined sample size in QT

Tags: c++, qt, audio, qt6

I am creating a player but I need to read only 1024 samples of the audio file at once. Currently, I am able to read the file completely through QMultimedia class. Can I read a fixed sample-sized audio file using QT?

Comment: Take a look at: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiodecoder.html

Comment: @scopchanov can I change the buffer size here in the QAudioDecoder library?

Comment: It does not seem like you can.